# Possible to use alcali solution to discharge static electricity?

Tags: electrostatics, electrochemistry

My question may contain wrong assumptions:

- I believe static electricity present in a workshop because of friction may be caused by electrons or negative ions
- I believe that it is somehow possible to conduct these charges in a copper wire to the ground

If the copper wire is going into a bucket of alcali water (ex. PH 12 mixture of water and sodium hydroxide), will it be able to discharge static from the workshop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not uncommon to use an electrically conductive bracelet, connected to a flexible electrically cable, to conduct electricitity between a person and the table he/she is working on, so that sparks can't jump between the person and things touching the table.  This is close to what you are suggesting.  The bucket of alkali solution, though, is not necessary.  Only electrical contact between oerson and table is required.  In cases where stray voltages may cause problems, e.g. in roll-to roll machinery, either cables with conductive brushes, ion generators, or even radioactive bars are used to provide conductive paths to dissipate static charge.